# @Transactional (readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED) is throwing exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using spring with hibernate and using spring transaction manager. I have the below method which is called from another method which is transactional.

```
@Transactional (readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public Map<String, String> getAllProperties ()
{  }
```

The problem I am facing is ; if I run this I am getting the below exception

```
Could not commit Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: commit failed
```

But instead if I change the annotation to the blow one or remove the annotation properties it just works fine

```
 @Transactional (readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public Map<String, String> getAllProperties ()
{  }
```

I felt its kind of strange as I am changing only the readOnly property.

can somebody please explain this

Comment: What are you doing inside your method? Are you modifying hibernate mapped instances?

Comment: You cannot call commit in a read only transaction.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to modify some data in database its not possible with `readOnly = true`.
Its ok if you want to retrieve some data set.

So when it comes to `UPDATE` or `INSERT` use `readOnly = false`.

GOOD LUCK.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are modifying the list/object that was received from hibernate within the `getAllProperties()` method.

If you provide more details of the implementation it would help.

In the meantime, do not perform any operation on the list/object returned by Hibernate (except a get* operation).
Even if you remove an element from the list (for filtration) that would try to change the underlying values in your database.